# GraphQL product quantity in stock

Tags: magento2, graphql

I'm trying to get the stock quantity of my products via graphql, here is my query, but the quantity is obviously not in the schema. Am I wrong? Is there a possibility to get it somehow? 
request:

```
{products(filter: {sku: {like: "024-%"}}) {
    total_count
    items {
    sku, delivery, name
    }    
  }
}
```

response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "products": {
      "total_count": 101,
      "items": [
        {
          "sku": "024-0010-1-0004",
          "delivery": "0",
          "name": "Zeller Keramik Platzset 43 x 30 cm Hahn & Henne"
        },
       ...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible as of yet and I'm not sure it will be implemented in the future since, usually, on frontend you don't need the exact qty. You can `stock_status` or `only_x_left_in_stock`. If you need the qty, you need to create a module and extend the products graphql query. There's an example in the *vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory-graph-ql/etc/schema.graphqls* module.